# How many printings have there been for Hollow Earth Expedition?

Tags: hollow-earth-expedition

The latest printing for the *Hollow Earth Expedition* core rule book to my knowledge is 2007 2nd printing. Have there been any since that one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, 2007 was the most recent printing.

Comment: Most recent, and *first*, making the count 1. (And it was in 2006.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sorry, that is inaccurate. The second printing was in January of 2007. First was August 2006. I am unaware of additional runs. Still one edition, however.

Comment: My mistake. Yes, I was thinking editions rather than printings.

Comment: No worries, no harm, no foul~